# How to set up the filtering in Drupal Views to target the correct CiviCRM Activity

Tags: activities

I've got a Drupal View that identifies a specific activity within a case and provides a link to the activity using its ID number. It appears to be working correctly in the majority of use cases, where I can simply filter out deleted cases, and filter on the activity type, status and current revision to find the right activity.

However, in some cases the view is showing me a link to an activity which I can't see when I view the 'Manage Case' screen. Indeed the activity ID that the view is presenting doesn't even show up when I search within CiviCRM for activities that match the other filters I'm using in the view.

It looks like CiviCRM - at least in the version I'm using in this case - is changing the ID number of activities when the activity gets edited?

Comment: Can you find that activity id anywhere in the system?  I'm on 4.6.3 and have never noticed activity ids changing on editing.  Are the activities created through a webform or the Civi UI?

Comment: Have you filtered on Case Type?

Comment: any chance it is related to Deleted Cases?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Deleted cases are filtered out, and I am filtering on case type. I do think there is an issue with the activity IDs. for example, if I file an activity on a case the ID changes, so I think the next step is to upgrade - we're running 4.4.5 I think at present, so I'll move it up to 4.5.x as a first step and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: hi Graham, I've come across the same issue. Within a case you would expect the activities to keep the same IDs, but what I've noticed is that in the database CiviCRM will create duplicate activities (as a copy). This does mean the activity ID won't be the same next time you use it.

Answer (score 2):

When you edit a case activity, it creates a new version of it, and that does indeed have a different ID.